Don't make it look like I'm question or answer banned while I'm actually suspended
When you are suspended and attempt to ask or answer a question, you are given the Question/Answer banned popup (screenshot of the question popup below):

Similarly, for answers, the message is telling users "Sorry, we are no longer accepting answers from your account because most of your answers need improvement or do not sufficiently answer the question. See the Help Center to learn more."
These messages are extremely problematic and incorrect. Probably the only part of these messages that is not harmful is "do not create a new account". Everything else is completely false and misleading. In many cases, a suspension could have nothing to do with your previous history of questions or answers. In addition, the question message telling someone "the only way to get unbanned is to edit and improve your questions" is confusing when they can't edit. The question message also tells users that they can contribute to the site in other ways, which is again false when suspended. Not only that, but when users are inevitably confused, they may try looking at the link to the help center page, which in both messages is completely false and useless for this users actual situation.
Could this message be removed and replaced with a correct, useful, and relevant message describing the user's situation and what they should do?

I guess it's because normally 1 rep users can still post, so instead of writing special code for the case of suspended users, they also changed the "IsAccountPostBanned" bit to 1, thus blocking the account from posting without any further coding.

Also, by the way - did you get suspended on purpose just to find bugs? ;-)

@ShadowWizard But honestly suspensions are quite buggy. I spent like 5-10 minutes trying to find bugs I found 4 (including this one) that weren't already reported.

I'd generally consider this feature request to be more important than oddball bugs with the suspension functionality. I don't really mind if the experience a suspended user has is a little bit (within reason obviously!) broken and undefined. I do care if they're being fed information that's just wrong, like what this feature request describes. I support a fix/change here wholeheartedly.

@Spevacus Status-review maybe?

This is already reported: When a suspended user tries to ask a question, the screen looks the exact same as an automatic question ban

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog That report has the user recieving a different message and doesn't mention the answer piece. Please reopen.

"But honestly suspensions are quite buggy" tell me about it! We suspended users get no respect! :P

@Jeremy Well in fairness suspended users are a small portion of users. They are also unable to actually contribute. Many of them are clearly just trolls out to harm the site who will never contribute positively. I do understand why limited resources are put into them. On the other hand...some suspended users come back to be amazing contributors. Some now have diamonds.

You can post an answer to that question stating it also applies for attempted answers. It's the same root cause either way - the suspension system imposes automatic post bans, and I don't see why we need two separate reports about it.
